# Selecionar dia especifico em um np.array contendo datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

Tenho um **np.array.astype('Datetime[s]')** chamado **T** com vários dias em horários aleatórios. Preciso selecionar alguns dias para separação.

Tentei:

```
for i in np.arange(MinTime,MaxTime,np.timedelta64(1, 'D')):
    mask = (T > i) & (T < (i + np.timedelta64(1, 'D')))
    print (T[mask])
```

Porém somar um dia trás problemas pois um dia qualquer **i** retorna parte do dia posterior também.
Obviamente da para resolver isto, mas pergunto **se há alguma forma mais numpy/pandas/python de selecionar datas qualquer somente com o dia, algo como**:

```
print(T[T == '01-01-2006'])
```

Veja que:

```
print (T[T == np.datetime64('01-01-2006')])
```

retorna **somente** o dia 01-01-2006 A MEIA NOITE porém eu preciso de todas as ocorrências de 01-01-2006.

Answer (score 0):

```
T[T.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")=='2006-01-01']
```

ou

```
T[((T-np.datetime64('01-01-2006')).days==0)]
```

deveria funcionar